# Why do I get a Postman socket hangup if I am connected to the database?

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

I have an Express/TypeScript API and I am attempting to create a new patient in Postman, I am passing in all the required properties according to my `EmrPatient` model file here:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

// # 1. What it takes to create a Patient
// An interface that describes the properties
// that are required to create a new patient
interface EmrPatientAttrs {
  emrId: string
  clinicId?: string | number
  patientId: string | number
  doctorId: string | number
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  gender: string
  dob: string
  address?: string
  city?: string
  state?: string
  zipCode?: number
  alunaPatientId?: string | number
  alunaDoctorId?: string | number
}

// # 2. What the entire Patient collections looks like
// An interface that describes the properties that 
// an EmrPatient Model has
// This essentially tells TypeScript that there is going to be a 
// build function available on this EmrPatientModel
// So TypeScript, there is a build function 
// and these are the required arguments to call it.
// Now TypeScript understands what an EmrPatientModel is 
interface EmrPatientModel extends mongoose.Model<EmrPatientDoc> {
  build(attrs: EmrPatientAttrs): EmrPatientDoc;
}

// # 3. What properties a single user has
// An interface that describes the properties that
// an EmrPatient Document has
interface EmrPatientDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  emrId: string
  clinicId?: string | number
  patientId: string | number
  doctorId: string | number
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  gender: string
  dob: string
  address?: string
  city?: string
  state?: string
  zipCode?: number
  alunaPatientId?: string | number
  alunaDoctorId?: string | number
}

const emrPatientSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    emrId: { type: String, required: true },
    clinicId: { type: String, required: false },
    patientId: { type: String, required: true },
    doctorId: { type: String, required: true },
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    gender: { type: String, required: true },
    dob: { type: Date, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: false },
    city: { type: String, required: false },
    state: { type: String, required: false },
    zipCode: { type: Number, required: false },
    alunaPatientId: { type: String, required: false },
    alunaDoctorId: { type: String, required: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)
emrPatientSchema.statics.build = (attrs: EmrPatientAttrs) => {
  return new EmrPatient(attrs);
};

const EmrPatient = mongoose.model<EmrPatientDoc, EmrPatientModel>('EmrPatient', emrPatientSchema);

// problem now is we have to import more things from this file,
// not convenient
// How do we make building/creating a Patient/Doctor similar to before?
// to avoid the high mental burden of having to remember to import 
// buildPatient/buildDoctor

export { EmrPatient }
```

This is my route:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { EmrDoctor } from '../models/EmrDoctor';
import { EmrPatient } from '../models/EmrPatient';
import { DatabaseConnectionError } from "../middlewares/database-connection-error";

const partnerRouter = express.Router()

partnerRouter.post('/api/v3/partner/patients', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log("Creating a patient...");
  throw new DatabaseConnectionError();
});
```

I think my code is sound, so I am unclear where the problem is.

The expected result here is a 201 Created.

This is the Postman json data:

```
[
    {
        "emrId": "123", 
        "patientId": "abc", 
        "doctorId": "196", 
        "firstName": "Harry", 
        "lastName": "Smith", 
        "gender": "maile", 
        "dob": "March 31, 1990"
    }
]
```

I was able to add some better programmatic error handling and it seems the issue is that it's not connecting to the database, yet when I first start the app, it says connected to the database:

```
import express from "express";
import { json } from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { partnerRouter } from "./routes/partner-routes";
import { errorHandler } from "./middlewares/error-handler";

const app = express();
app.use(json());

app.use(partnerRouter);

app.use(errorHandler);

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/auth", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000!");
  });
};

start();
```

Comment: what is your expected result, your test data, your actual outcome?

Comment: @tbjgolden, 201 Created.

Comment: Do you have the Postman json data you're sending to check? It might be correctly telling you your payload is incomplete or broken

Comment: @tbjgolden, I added it above.

Comment: not an expert in mongoose, but could it be the formatting of the date you've used? perhaps using an iso date might work?

Comment: @tbjgolden, yeah I actually tried `2022-03-28` before the above.

Comment: @tbjgolden, I added some better error handling and it seems it is having problems connecting to database when I make the request, even though upon boot it connects to the database.

Answer (score 0):

On your mongoose.connect remove the arguments. [Those are deprecated](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options).
It should be

```
try {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/auth");
    console.log('Connected to database');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

also from your code you aren't responding with anything in your `create patient` post method. you should `res.json({})` or `res.send()` rather than throw an error.

Comment: for version 6 and above, I have an older version of mongoose.

Comment: Are you doing the second part of the answer? you need to send a response. @Daniel